# Why FB SDK on iOS asks for permission for Friend List, when app does not ask for it

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When user tries to log in using Facebook app shows alert that says:

> "App name" would like to access your basic profile info and list of friends

Even though I do not ask for **list of friends** inside the app.
This is how I make the request:

```
fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email", "public_profile", "user_birthday"], fromViewController: vc) { (result, error) in
```

And I am not using user_friends anywhere in the app.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook reads the list of friends who are using your app by **default**. Please check with the Facebook developers portal.[image]

**Updated:**

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_birthday"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             NSLog(@"Result : %@", result);
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Yes it is and it appears I can not remove it?

Comment: Create a new app in https://developers.facebook.com/apps  set as live then try now.

Comment: Because list of friends permission is not showing in my side.

Comment: Just did it and either can turn all permissions including friends or none.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: _“Facebook reads the list of friends who are using your app by default”_ – that’s not true. Before API v2 was introduced, there wasn’t a separate permission for this, and public_profile included access to the user’s friends. But nowadays you need to ask for `user_friends` permission. And your app will only get to see friends that have granted the permission on their end as well.

Comment: Is it possible to remove on "list of friends" from permission pop up (i used ACAccountStore)?